# Boost io_service.accept : Get URI called

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I would like to get the URI called with boost.

If `http://localhost:8080/users/4` is called, I want to know the URI or just `/users/4`

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8080));
  tcp::socket socket(io);
  acceptor.accept(socket);

  // Do stuff to get URI
  // ...

  if (uri == "http://localhost:8080/users/4") {
     std::cout << "User 4 uri called" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its more question about how to read asio socket and how to parse http protocol, than about asio itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look to the [ASIO's http server example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server). The `connection::handle_read` method parses a request, using the `request_parser` class instance, as result, an instance of the [`request`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server2/request.hpp) structure contains an URI which is required.

Comment: After a long search, I still do not understand how they do to get that URI

Comment: I understand to get the URI. It's in http's header. Socket must be must and parse. Thank you.